# How can I change BaseUrl for twilio-csharp?

Tags: c#, .net, twilio

Due to last Twilio news about updating api.twilio.com with a SHA2-signed certificate, I decided to test my processes with api.twilio.com:8443. For REST requests I'm using [twilio-csharp](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp) via NuGet and now I'm trying to change the port for requests.
BaseUrl property has private set and is [hardcoded](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp/blob/master/src/Twilio.Api/Core.cs) in TwilioRestClient constructor.
Is there any way to change it for my tests?

Except downloading and changing base code with rebuild.

Comment: For NodeJS, I was able to successfully do the same. After the node client is created via var client = twilio(sid, token) set the host property to include 8443 like so: client.host = 'api.twilio.com:8443';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue as you did. The way that I did it was setting up a breakpoint right before I sent the text message and in the immediate window changed the BaseUrl to https://api.twilio.com:8443/. This helped me to test the new security changes they made. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can´t set these if using REST with .NET and Twilio.

Twilio in .NET is really very simple to use. You just have to point your Account, the Twilio Number and the correspondent Authentication Token, like this:

```
    Dim SMS As TwilioRestClient = New TwilioRestClient(Account, AuthToken)
    Dim SMS_Msg = SMS.SendMessage(Number2Use, ClientPhone, mensagem)
```

To maintain so easy structure, all required settings are within the Twilio API DLL - and because of it, you need to download it again and distribute it to your clients. You don´t need to rebuild your project, but only update the DLL.

Comment: So do we need to update the DLL for the new security change? I don't see any way to update the Base URL when calling the TwilioRestClient in CSharp.

Comment: That´s it. You cannot change the base URL via Twilio.